# Add new locale to existing Fredhopper instance

Tags: 2013, fredhopper, linux

I am trying to add a new locale to my existing Fredhopper instance but it is not working.

I have made the changes as suggested in the given link
[Fredhopper learning center](https://www.fredhopper.com/learningcenter/display/learningcenter/Add+a+new+universe+or+locale+to+Fredhopper)

But the locale is not reflecting in the Business Manager of the Fredhopper.

Below are the Fredhopper log for the instance prod

```
2015-11-16 03:01:06,129 INFO  [Fred-Initialisation-Thread] FASSearchIndexReader.java:70 50067 Loading text search index...
2015-11-16 03:01:06,146 INFO  [Fred-Initialisation-Thread] SearchEngineConfigurationMigrator.java:88 Engine catalog01-en_GB configuration version RULE_BASED_REDIRECTS is current, no migration.
2015-11-16 03:01:06,533 PROGRESS [Fred-Initialisation-Thread] CheckpointMaintenanceService.java:501 100024 QServer started using search index with checkpointId '20151105.080317-1' for searchEngineId 'catalog01-en_GB'.
2015-11-16 03:01:06,632 INFO  [Fred-Initialisation-Thread] SearchEngineConfigurationMigrator.java:88 Engine catalog01-en_US configuration version RULE_BASED_REDIRECTS is current, no migration.
2015-11-16 03:01:06,647 WARN  [Fred-Initialisation-Thread] DefaultCheckpointAcceptancePolicyImpl.java:44 40445 Checkpoint update to `20151105.080317-1' skipped: not required indices are contained for server `catalog01-en_US' || root@ip-10-120-11-252:/apps/fredhopper/data/installations/FAS fas-7.5.2.4@32caeb2eb85a1c8a2b7ae430a47fef7e2fe34432
2015-11-16 03:01:06,648 WARN  [Fred-Initialisation-Thread] DefaultCheckpointAcceptancePolicyImpl.java:44 40445 Checkpoint update to `20151105.080317' skipped: not required indices are contained for server `catalog01-en_US' ||
```

Thanks in advance.